# Trying to use ng-style conditionally

Tags: angularjs

The code below doesn't change any colors of the table. No red or green seen on the rows (except for the different labels being correctly rendered).

Any ideas?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Still standing?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="player in players" ng-style="player.standing ? '{'color':'green'}' : {'color':'red'}">
            <td ng-cloak>
                <span ng-show="player.standing">
                    {{player.name}}
                </span>
                <span ng-show="!player.standing">
                    <strike>{{player.name}}</strike>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td ng-cloak>{{ player.associatedNumber }}</td>
            <td ng-cloak>
                <span 
                    ng-class="player.standing ? 'label label-success': 'label label-danger'"
                    ng-show="player.standing">
                    Yes
                </span>
                <span 
                    ng-class="player.standing ? 'label label-success': 'label label-danger'"
                    ng-show="!player.standing">
                    No
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

dataset ..

```
[{
    "name": "Robert B",
        "associatedNumber": 21,
        "standing": true
}, {
    "name": "Martin C",
        "associatedNumber": 55,
        "standing": false
}, {
    "name": "Bobby B",
        "associatedNumber": 15,
        "standing": true
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression isn't producing a valid result for `ng-style`. You want

```
ng-style="{color: player.standing ? 'green' : 'red'}"
```

You could also use the corresponding [Bootstrap contextual text classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-colors) so these are aligned to the `label` classes in your other code

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in players" ng-class="{
    'text-success': player.standing,
    'text-danger': !player.standing}">
```

---

Also, your `ng-class` spans are a bit weird. Maybe try

```
<span class="label" ng-class="{
    'label-success': player.standing,
    'label-danger': !player.standing
}">{{player.standing ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</span>
```

instead of two spans with redundant logic.